# Shadow In IE9 Lags Animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just accompolished making shadow below a DIV in my web page which i have been testing in IE9,
By using the following piece of CSS:

```
#test  
 { 
 filter: 
 progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=black,direction=180,strength=3);     
 }
```

After Making this, The Jquery Animation in my page is seems to be lagging.
The problem still persists Even i tried to increase the animation speed in Jquery. 
Lagging get stops only when i remove the above mentioned code in my css. 
Any clues to fix this issue .?

Comment: box-shadow is supported in IE9+ ???

Comment: @adeneo It wont work in IE, [Refer This](http://www.kingofdevelopers.com/css-tips-and-tricks/drop-shadow.php)

Comment: Are you saying this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/krWLA/) does'nt work in IE9+ ????

Comment: @adeneo Yeah Its working in the fiddle you given, But just now i had replaced my olden css with yours, The shadow get vanished. It is not working.